# What is the max capacity of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the max capacity of `ArrayList` in Java? Since `ArrayList` uses an array internally its capacity will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, right?

This code shows the max capacity of `ArrayList` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{

transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

/**
 * The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains).
 *
 * @serial
 */
private int size;
 /**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate (unless necessary).
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
}
```

Yet when I do `new ArrayList<>(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` the following error is emitted:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This code shows the max capacity of `ArrayList` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

No, it doesn't. It shows the max capacity to be:

```java
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

Notice the `8` being subtracted from the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Also, keep in mind this is only the max capacity *assuming enough memory*. An OOME may be thrown for a smaller capacity if the JVM does not have enough free memory available to allocate the necessary array.